# The constraints doesn't work as I expected

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views like this:

[image]

I setup the vertical space constraints:

[image]

As you see, the constraint between BottomView's top and TopView's bottom is 0. But unfortunately it's not true when I click the **Toggle** button to move the Top View. Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func onToggle(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.topView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -self.topView.bounds.height)
}
```

It's the same even if I add :

```
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

The result is:

[image]

Apparently the margin between the TopView's bottom and BottomView's top is not 0. The auto layout doesn't work. Did I miss anything? Thanks

**P.S.**: I know there is another way to solve this issue. For example, to change the frame of the BottomView when the toggle is pressed. But my question is why the autolayout doesn't work as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it maybe related to the TopView's constraint. The TopView's frame changed when you apply the translate transform to the top view. So that its top margin constraint changed too. That will affect the top margin constraint of the bottom view.

My suggestion is don't apply the translate transform for the UIView. Instead change the top view's top vertical space constraint.

```
    self.topConstraint.constant = -self.topView.bounds.height
```

The bottom view will follow the top view in this way. That means the autolayout actually works. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like iOS 8 has a bug with resizing UILabel height constraint.

Anyhow, assuming your two views are not UILabels, the method I suggest is to use is create a property that remembers the height constraint for your top view:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *topView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *bottomView;

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// We will animate this NSLayoutConstraint's constant value
// -----------------------------------------------------------
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *topViewHeightConstraint;

@end
```

Then setup our views and toggle button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self initViews];
    [self initConstraints];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)initViews
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Toggle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleTopView)];

    self.topView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203.0/255.0 green:89.0/255.0 blue:91.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    self.bottomView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:103.0/255.0 green:167.0/255.0 blue:187.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [self.view addSubview:self.topView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomView];
}

-(void)initConstraints
{
    self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.topView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.bottomView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    id views = @{
                 @"topView": self.topView,
                 @"bottomView": self.bottomView
                 };

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[topView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottomView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topView][bottomView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    self.topViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.topView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                               multiplier:1.0 constant:170.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.topViewHeightConstraint];
}

-(void)toggleTopView
{
    if(self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant != 0)
    {
        self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant = 170.0;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];


}
```

You get this at first:

[image: screenshot 1]

Then when you tap on the toggle button, we set the heightConstraint property constant to be 0:

```
-(void)toggleTopView
{
    if(self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant != 0)
    {
        self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.topViewHeightConstraint.constant = 170.0;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
}
```

you get a smooth collapsing animation of the red:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Thanks. I use the same method to create the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Transforms on views are applied after the rest of the layout code is completed. This includes Auto-layout so if you change the transform of a view it will not affect auto-layout. The transform will be relative to wherever auto-layout has placed the view.